# Android custom View with ViewOutlineProvider adds white border before shadow

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view where I am drawing a rectangle on the canvas. To add shadow/elevation to that custom view I am using ViewOutlineProvider as below:

```
private class CustomOutline extends ViewOutlineProvider {

    int width;
    int height;

    CustomOutline(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setRect(0, 0, width, height);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            outline.offset(5,5);
        }
    }
}
```

And calling setOutlineProvider when the view size changes.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setOutlineProvider(new CustomOutline(w, h));
    }
}
```

I am getting a shadow as shown in the below screenshot. If you notice closely, you will find a white line before the shadow (between red rectangle and its shadow). 
I am struggling with couple of things though

- How can I remove that white line?
- How to make the shadow to show on the upper side as well?
- Also is there a way to prevent the pixelation when the view is at an angle?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try set outline.setAlpha(0),like this:

```
 @Override
 public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setAlpha(0);//add this
        outline.setRect(0, 0, width, height);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            outline.offset(5,5);
        }
    }
```